# Is it possible to get exactly once processing with Spring Cloud Stream?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

Currently I'm using SCS with almost default configuration for sending and receiving message between microservices.
Somehow I've read this
https://www.confluent.io/blog/enabling-exactly-kafka-streams

and wonder that it is gonna works or not if we just put the property called "processing.guarantee" with value "exactly-once" there through properties in Spring boot application ?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your question you should look at Spring Cloud Stream as just a delegate between target system (e.g., Kafka) and your code. The binders that enable such delegation are usually implemented in such way that they propagate whatever functionality supported by the target system.

Comment: @ekbunditw Sorry for commenting on this a bit late, but just to complement what Oleg said, Spring Cloud Stream does not do anything special for achieving exactly once delivery guarantees, however, you can use the property you mentioned to achieve it since the target platform in this case (Apache Kafka) supports it.