# Spring Cloud Stream vs Kafka Stream for Exactly Once feature

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

I was not able to find here and on Spring website and blogs if Spring Cloud Stream is able to provide "Exactly Once" semantic provided by Kafka Stream APIs.
Maybe there is not a single configuration/annotation and in the thread "[Is it possible to get exactly once processing with Spring Cloud Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54211885/is-it-possible-to-get-exactly-once-processing-with-spring-cloud-stream)" I can find something useful, but the answer is a very high level from expert. 
Thanks for help

Comment: Exactly once feature is not delimited to Kafka streams. You can write your own producer and send messages exactly once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream does not do anything particular regarding processing guarantees. You can delegate that to Kafka Streams by providing the `processing.guarantee` property and setting that to `exactly-once`. See [this](https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#processing-guarantee) for more details. When using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams binder, you can provide this as a property to the Spring Boot application as below.

`spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.processing.guarantee`.

Keep in mind that Kafka Stream's exactly once guarantee only works if you are writing the results back to Kafka.